# Simulate input press when pressing a div in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, file, input, styles

I want to style a simple file upload system, I want that when a user clicks on an element (a div lets say) the input is pressed.

Something like:

```
$("#mydiv").click(function() {
 $("#myinput").browse();
});
```

Comment: Have you tried `focus()` instead of `browse()`? Or `click()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use .trigger() to start an event on an element.

```
$("#mydiv").click(function() {
 $("#myinput").trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: `trigger('click')` is equivalent to calling `click()` (without arguments or a function); so it should work fine, just a little more verbose than necessary. (Sorry, I didn't mean to come across quite so... picky.)

Answer (score 1):

Try [.focus()](http://api.jquery.com/focus/)

```
$("#mydiv").click(function () {
    $("#myinput").focus(); // or $("#myinput").click();
});
```